# Could the Wraith Serve As Hosts to the Gou'ald?

Tags: stargate, goauld

In the Stargate television franchise, did the shows' developers ever consider letting the Goa'uld use the Wraith as hosts? It seems like a perfectly logical NEW direction that would have at least left a way open for a new threat.

Comment: the goa'uld havnt, and i would hazard they might be slightly incompatible, but if so the goa'uld are fairly skilled with genetics and could figure out a way to make wraith habitable.

Comment: I'm not going to conclusively answer that they never considered it, but it never happens and is, to the best of my recollection, never discussed. As with many things in TV, the answer to whether it's possible amounts to 'if it's convenient for the plot'. I could make reasonable-sounding arguments either way, based on what we know of the physiology of the species involved. Since it never came up, we'll probably never know.

Comment: Why exactly would a possessed wraith be a new threat beyond that there would now be a gou'ld who not only keeps humans as slaves but now actively eats them on occasion instead of merely working them to death in a mine

Comment: The wraith (like most evil aliens) are stronger than humans, have a technology base that can be expanded upon, existing components of civilization, a predilection to killing others and each other. They're also tougher to kill and are related to humans and those bugs. They'd be perfect hosts.

Comment: Goa'uld Wraith? Holy [nightmare fuel](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NightmareFuel), Batman!

Answer (score 4):

the question header and question dont match

as to the header we never see a gou'ld try to possess a wraith however we have seen a gou'ld possess at least 3 separate species humans, unas and the creature that was placed in the sarcophagus with Marduk.  If the gou'ld can possess a species so dissimilar to that of its other hosts it stands to reason they could possess a wraith.

Answer (score 1):

Although we haven't yet see a wraith become a Goa'uld host, its certainly possible.  I think the reason it was left out was because the Warith are already powerful enough as they are.